# Fetching rows from file_1 based on another file_2

Tags: linux, awk, file-comparison

I have a tab delimted text file as follows:

file_1:

```
A1  13f  Jos  +
B1  zh4  Kia  -
C2  nh2  Met  -
D3  5gh  Lox  +
F4  w4t  Nit  -
```

file_2

```
N3  6jg  Jut -
J8  76d  Met +
A1  99g  Kia -
M6  45k  Qox +
V2  87h  Nit -
```

I would like to extract the entries from file_1 where 3rd column entries match with 3rd column entries of file_2 like follows in linux:

```
    B1  zh4  Kia -   
    C2  nh2  Met -    
    F4  w4t  Nit -
```

Will `comm-12 file_1.txt file_2.txt` help? Kindly guide me

Comment: I don't understand. The first ouput line comes from file 2, but lines 2 and 3 come from file 1.

Comment: @choroba I have edited the question. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: shall not the line with 'kia' come before "Met'. Is there any requirement on the ordering of the output lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` is probably simplest here (this preserves `file_1` input order):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR { seen[$3]++; next } seen[$3]' file_2 file_1

B1  zh4  Kia  -
C2  nh2  Met  -
F4  w4t  Nit  -
```

- Pattern `NR==FNR` only matches lines from the first input file (`file_2`) and builds up an associative array of all 3rd-column values with action `{ seen[$3]++; next }`

  - `seen[$3]++` is a common idiom for constructing an associative containing the set of unique field values: accessing key `$3` (the value of the 3rd field) in array `seen` implicitly *creates* an entry for that key on first access, and post-increment `++` gives the entry a nonzero value, which evaluates to true in a Boolean context (which the pattern discussed below takes advantage of).
- Due to the `next` in the previous action, pattern `seen[$3]` is then only executed for the second input file (`file_1`) and only evaluates to true if the second file's 3rd-column value was also present in the first file. A pattern that evaluates to true implicitly prints the line at hand.

Comment: +1 for excellent answer. Alhough I have a question about the order. This will print 'Kia' before 'Met'...is there a way to have the order follow the order from file2..Question shows 'Met' before 'Kia'

Comment: Thanks, @JayRajput. I had assumed that the OP's true intent was to preserve `file_1` input order, despite originally inconsistent sample output (which the OP has since corrected).

Comment: yup. saw that... now waiting for the OP to accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

`comm` expects the files to be sorted by the columns to compare, and the space before its arguments isn't optional.

But you can extract the third column of file 1 with `cut`, and extract that values from file 2 with `grep` if they can't appear in any other column:

```
cut -f3 file_1 | grep -Ff- file_2
```

The order of the lines corresponds to file2, though.

```
B1      zh4     Kia     -
C2      nh2     Met     -
F4      w4t     Nit     -
```

To get the right order, I'd use Perl:

```
perl -e 'until (eof) {
             @F = split " ", <>;
             $h{ $F[2] } = 1;
         }
         while (<>) {
             @F = split " ";
             print if $h{ $F[2] };
         }' file_1 file_2
```

It first stores the third column (`$F[2]`) values of file_1 into the hash `%h`, then it goes over file_2 and checks whether the value of column 3 was set in the hash.

Answer (score 0):

awk answer. This is OK for small files. For large files, the array seen will become huge as the complete line `$0` is kept in the array.

```
awk 'NR==FNR { seen[$3] = $0; next} $3 in seen {print seen[$3]}' file_2 file_1
```

**Output**

```
A1  99g  Kia -
J8  76d  Met +
V2  87h  Nit -
```

Comment: That's an interesting variation, but note that it will only work if there are no duplicates in the 3rd column of `file_2`; otherwise, you'll lose output lines.